# sql split row value before and after substring

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that contains a list of names. However, some rows contain the name and the alias separated by `, f/k/a—`, `, f/k/a` or `, n/k/a` . I'm trying to split the names and aliases into separate rows. Can someone please help?

Sample data below:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   ID  |                       Name                      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   Evil Empire, f/k/a - Starbucks                |
|   2   |   Aubrey Drake Graham, n/k/a Drake              |
|   3   |   Thomas Johnson Bridge, f/k/a Solomans Bridge  |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Desired output below:

```
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   ID  |                       Name                      |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   Evil Empire                                   |
|   1.1 |   Starbucks                                     |
|   2   |   Aubrey Drake Graham                           |
|   2.1 |   Drake                                         |
|   3   |   Thomas Johnson Bridge                         |
|   3.1 |   Solomans Bridge                               |
|---------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: I would probably do this in an User Defined Function

Comment: @Kevin thanks, could you please explain how?

Comment: I will not write the code for you, but general processing would be 1) Loop through records 2) Test if split string is found (for all cases) 3) Split the record 4) Add to a new table that the function will return.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?  in 2016 and later you can use `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: @Wouter I have version 2018. I can see `STRING_SPLIT` in the auto-populate suggestions but when I try to use it, it says it's not a recognized built-in function which is puzzling.

Comment: @Kevin  There is not need to use a loop for this.  Looping is almost always the wrong approach when using SQL.

Comment: @Chipmunk_da  Do you have your compatibility level set to a lower version than 2016?  If so, you will be able to see the newer functions, but not actually use them.

Comment: Are there only ever 2 values to be split from the Name column?

Comment: @SteveC Yes, there's always the name and an alias

Comment: @iamdave Not sure, but let me figure out how to check that

Comment: @iamdave - how would you do this and get the desired output e.g. "1.1" and check each case for the different delimiters using just `STRING_SPLIT`

Comment: @Kevin Using set based logic as per my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for ordinal splitter.  It's a simple unpivot using CROSS APPLY

[EDIT] Changed method of splitting to look for '%/%/%' in cases where there's an alias

```
select cast(unpvt.id as varchar(9))+iif(unpvt.seq=1, '', '.1') ID,
       trim(replace(replace(replace(unpvt.[Name],'f/k/a - ',''),'f/k/a ',''),'n/k/a ','')) [Name]
from (values (1, 'Evil Empire, f/k/a - Starbucks'),
             (2, 'Aubrey Drake Graham, n/k/a Drake'),
             (3, 'Thomas Johnson Bridge, f/k/a Solomans Bridge'),
             (4, 'Thomas, J, Cat, f/k/a Solomans,,,Bridge'),
             (5, 'Thomas')) v(id, [Name])
     cross apply (values (v.id, substring(v.[Name], 1, patindex('%/%/%', v.Name)-4), 1),
                         (v.id, substring(v.[Name], patindex('%/%/%', v.Name)-1, len(v.[Name])), 2)) unpvt(id, [Name], seq)
where patindex('%/%/%', v.[Name])>1;
```

Results

```
ID  Name
1   Evil Empire
1.1 Starbucks
2   Aubrey Drake Graham
2.1 Drake
3   Thomas Johnson Bridge
3.1 Solomans Bridge
4   Thomas, J, Cat
4.1 Solomans,,,Bridge
```

Comment: Nice answer.  Should make the OP aware that this will only work with the one alias.  If the data were to ever have 2 aliases, this approach would stop working.

Comment: That was already confirmed in the comments above.  Thnx for the edit :)

Comment: What if the data had an extra comma in it? It will work for the limited data set now though

Comment: @Kevin that's an issue for any method of splitting the string and not just this one.

Comment: Thanks! Just realised that the column also contains values where there's no alias and this wouldn't work for that. Trying to figure out how to handle that

Comment: Plus, the alias can contain a `,` like `Solomans, Bridge` and the current solution won't be able handle that as it'll split `Solomans` and `Bridge` into two rows.

Answer (score 1):

As you can't use the built in `string_split` you will need to add a Table Valued Function to do that for you.  Using one of these allows you to split your data like this:

### Query

```
declare @t table(ID int,[Name] varchar(100));
insert into @t values
 (1,'Evil Empire, f/k/a - Starbucks')
,(2,'Aubrey Drake Graham, n/k/a Drake')
,(3,'Thomas Johnson Bridge, f/k/a Solomans Bridge')
;

select case when s.rn = 1
            then t.ID
            else t.ID + ((s.rn - 1)/10.)
            end as ID
      ,replace(replace(replace(s.item,' f/k/a - ',''),' f/k/a ',''),' n/k/a ','')
from @t as t
    cross apply dbo.fn_StringSplit4k(t.[Name],',',null) as s
order by t.ID
        ,s.rn;
```

### Output

```
+----------+-----------------------+
|    ID    |         Name          |
+----------+-----------------------+
| 1.000000 | Evil Empire           |
| 1.100000 | Starbucks             |
| 2.000000 | Aubrey Drake Graham   |
| 2.100000 | Drake                 |
| 3.000000 | Thomas Johnson Bridge |
| 3.100000 | Solomans Bridge       |
+----------+-----------------------+
```

### Function

```
create function [dbo].[fn_StringSplit4k]
(
     @str nvarchar(4000) = ' '              -- String to split.
    ,@delimiter as nvarchar(20) = ','       -- Delimiting value to split on.
    ,@num as int = null                     -- Which value to return.
)
returns table
as
return
                    -- Start tally table with 10 rows.
    with n(n)   as (select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1)

                    -- Select the same number of rows as characters in @str as incremental row numbers.
                    -- Cross joins increase exponentially to a max possible 10,000 rows to cover largest @str length.
        ,t(t)   as (select top (select len(isnull(@str,'')) a) row_number() over (order by (select null)) from n n1,n n2,n n3,n n4)

                    -- Return the position of every value that follows the specified delimiter.
        ,s(s)   as (select 1 union all select t+1 from t where case when @delimiter = '' and t < len(@str) then 1 else case when substring(isnull(@str,''),t,1) = @delimiter then 1 else 0 end end = 1)

                    -- Return the start and length of every value, to use in the SUBSTRING function.
                    -- ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the last value where there is no delimiter at the end of the string.
        ,l(s,l) as (select s,case when @delimiter = '' then 1 else isnull(nullif(charindex(@delimiter,isnull(@str,''),s),0)-s,4000) end from s)
    
    select rn
          ,item
    from(select row_number() over(order by s) as rn
                ,substring(@str,s,l) as item
        from l
        ) a
    where rn = @num
        or @num is null;
```

Comment: thanks for this, really helpful! I've now managed to change the compatibility level in SSMS am able to use the `STRING_SPLIT` function!

Comment: It seems that the `STRING_SPLIT` function doesn't have `rn` row number in the output, so I'm unable to use your solution. Could you please advise on how I can change your query to use the built-in `STRING_SPLIT` function? thanks!

Comment: More importantly, the alias can contain a `,` like `Solomans, Bridge` and the current solution won't be able handle that as it'll split `Solomans` and `Bridge` into two rows.